# Why is EWW unable to place images into tables

Tags: images, eww, shr

Web pages are rendered with the simple html renderer `shr` in the Emacs webbrowser EWW. Pitingly, images in tables are displayed below the tables.

The source code of `shr` contains the [following comment](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/f131e396f8a32003b795456130ea37efa6ff41eb/lisp/net/shr.el#L2113-L2115) about that:

> ```
>     ;; Finally, insert all the images after the table.  The Emacs buffer
>     ;; model isn't strong enough to allow us to put the images actually
>     ;; into the tables.  It inserts also non-td/th objects.
> ```

Is that actually true? Shr already uses `window-text-pixel-size` for calculating the width of columns.

Furthermore, one can adjust column positions fine grained with the help of the `:align-to` space width specifiction.

The following code shows that `window-text-pixel-size` and `:align-to` work well with images:

```el
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*test*")
  (unless (and
           (intern-soft "img")
           (boundp 'img)
           (stringp img))
    (setq-local
     img
     (with-current-buffer
         (url-retrieve-synchronously
          "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/emacs/img/logo.svg?v=ceb7969787d0")
       (buffer-string))))
  (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
  (insert
   "initial string"
   (propertize " " 'display '(space :align-to (10 . cm)))
   "second column"
   "\nImg: ")
  (insert-image (create-image
                 img
                 nil
                 t))
  (insert
   " text behind "
   (propertize " " 'display '(space :align-to (10 . cm)))
   "2nd column")
  (let ((wnd (display-buffer (current-buffer))))
    (cons
     (car
      (window-text-pixel-size
       wnd
       (goto-char (point-min))
       (progn
         (search-forward "second column")
         (match-beginning 0))))
     (car
      (window-text-pixel-size
       wnd
       (progn
         (forward-line)
         (point))
       (progn
         (search-forward "2nd column")
         (match-beginning 0)))))))
```

The code returns `(377 . 377)` meaning that `x-window-text-pixel-width` perfectly calculates the width of the rows belonging to the first column.

A screenshot of the produced buffer:

[image: buffer with :align-to and window-text-pixel-size]

It shows that the rows of the second column are perfectly aligned.

**Question:** What is the actual limitation that is addressed in the above quotation?

Emacs-Version: `GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-09-16`

Comment: Yes this would be nice if emacs could do that, it is at least capable of showing images side by side.